# Why does Kotlin's split("") function result in a leading and trailing empty string?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm a Java developer who tried Kotlin and found a counterintuitive case between these two languages.

Consider the given code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
"???".split("")  # gives ["", "?", "?", "?", ""]
```

and the same in Java:

```java
"???".split("")  # gives ["?", "?", "?"]
```

Why does Kotlin produce a leading and trailing empty space string in the resulting array? Or does Java always removes these empty strings, and I just wasn't aware of that?

I know that there is the `toCharArray()` method on each Kotlin `String`, but still, it's not very intuitive (maybe the Java developers should give up old habits from Java which they were hoping to reuse in a new language?).

Comment: "Let's discuss" No, Stack Overflow is not a place for discussions.

Comment: @Sweeper While this is technically true, it's still an interesting question that will probably have a very concrete answer and therefor it suits the QA format very well. I once had a similar "why standard library is the way it is" and I added it here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Still not sure if this was the right place for it though. At least no one complained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the Java [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method explicitly removes them:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

[`split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) mentions:

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring.

`""` is a zero-width match. Not sure why you consider `toCharArray()` to not be intuitive here, splitting by an empty string to iterate over all characters is a roundabout way of doing things. `split()` is intended to pattern match and get groups of Strings.

PS: I checked JDK 8, 11 and 17, behavior seems to be consistent for a while now.

Comment: My concerns about `toCharArray()` was from that I assumed (as you see incorrectly) Kotlin API behaves the same as Java one. Thank you for your clarification - from now I will be more careful with such assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the first and last element:

```
"???".split("").drop(1).dropLast(1)
```

Check out this example:

```
"".split("")   // [, ]
```

> Splits this char sequence to a list of strings around occurrences of the specified delimiters.

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html